# ionic 4 - http is found as undefined

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to get some information from my Service using http on ionic.

I followed the tutorial found in the documentation:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http

I currently have a class where I can access my service and handle the data

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class Repositorio {

    constructor(private http: HTTP) { }

    CarregaDados() {

        this.http.get('http://ionic.io', {}, {})
            .then(data => {

                console.log(data.status);
                console.log(data.data); // data received by server
                console.log(data.headers);

            })
            .catch(error => {

                console.log(error.status);
                console.log(error.error); // error message as string
                console.log(error.headers);

            });

    }
}
```

however he always returns me the following error

> core.js:9110 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'get' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'get'
>   of undefined

if i give a console log in http, i see that it is undefined, why it happens and how to treat it?

Comment: Use HttpClient instead.. `import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';`

Comment: `@ionic-native/http/ngx` works only in Devices. if you want to use / debug http requests in browser you should Use. `import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'`

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the `HTTP` into providers in the app.module.ts?

```
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [HTTP]
  ...
```

Comment: Hello, I just added HTTP to my app.module.ts and the problem continues. I have other module, should I add in others?

Comment: No need. It should work anywhere if you added it into the app.module.ts. Can you please make sure the plugin is installed successfully? `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http`

Comment: Look at the message he returned to me
"Cordova-plugin-advanced-http" plugin already installed on android.

Comment: Could the problem be due to the order of HTTP? it's correct that way
  providers: [
     StatusBar,
     SplashScreen,
     HTTP,
     {provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy}
   ]

Comment: No it doesn't matter. Can you please try to uninstall the plugin and the ionic-native and try again: `ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-advanced-http`,  `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http`, `npm remove @ionic-native/http`, `npm install @ionic-native/http`

Comment: Good evening, thanks for the return. the following instructions and have not yet worked, the same error consists. do I have to do any config.xml configuration?
I received a message when I was adding http saying to add this preference "<preference name =" AndroidPersistentFileLocation "value =" Compatibility "/>" but only in new projects now what? Is there another method of using http?

Comment: I don't think it is related, but you can give it a try. Can you please try to create new app and check if the steps bellow worked?

Comment: I also added the preference and it didn't work, I will try to create a new application and follow these instructions as you said. :/

Comment: Hello, I created a new project and followed its instructions, the error no longer happens but now appears the following error message cordova is not available. I believe this is because I am giving an ionic serve and running through chrome. How do I run through chrome without this error?

Comment: Yes you're right. You will need to run it on emulator or on a real device. You will need this command: `ionic cordova run android` or `ionic cordova run ios`